# Stuff that the programming languages does not allow in its syntax

Tags: programming-languages, compiler-theory

There is some stuff that I never see in any programming language and I would know why. I believe this things may be useful. Wll,maybe the explanation will be obvious when you point. But let's go.

Why doesn't **10²**, **be valid in its syntax**? 
sometimes, we want express by using such notation(just like in a paper) instead of pre-computed value(that sometimes, is a big number,and,makes some difficult when seen at first time, I belive that it is the purpose to _ in the D and Java programming languages)  or still call math functions for this. Of course that I'm saying to the compiler replace the value of this variable to the computed value,don't leave it to at run-time.

The **-** in an indentifier. Why is - not acceptable like _?(just lisp dialect does) to me, `int name-size = 14;` does not means unreadable. Or this "limitation" is attribute to characters set of computer?

I will be so happy when someone answer my questions. Also,if you have another pointer to ask,just edit my answer and post a note on its edition or post as comment.

Comment: It's just a matter of implementation (how language designers have written syntax and parser). E.g. in some languages (for example, in [clojure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clojure#Examples), COBOL and FORTH) dash in identifiers is perfectly fine.

Comment: @om-nom-nom: I know that it's just degsiner choice. What I want to understand why. and yeah, I forget that is valid in listp dilect :) I will put this note and make another observation.

Comment: The problem with the - is that it is also an operator, e.g. if you have your `int name, size;`, to what refers `name-size`? To the variable name-size or the name minus size?

Comment: @TheMask it's hard to answer *why*. Why designers of some natural languages use diacritic (like garçon in french) where as in English we don't have any? Why romanians used their own digits (IV and so on) although most of the modern western world use arabic digits?

Comment: -1? really? I will remove this question.

Comment: This is a discussion question, and can't easily be answered here. Therefore, it's not appropriate for StackOverflow. (The [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) clearly says "practical, answerable questions based on actual problems you face".) Voting to close as "not constructive" for that reason. (I did NOT downvote your question, BTW; I simply voted to close it.)

Comment: I nearly downvoted *and* voted to close. I then considered how I *would* answer it, and worked out there were enough concrete and hopefully useful points to make to answer instead of downvoting/closing. It was a close call though.

Comment: @KenWhite While this question might not fit the "practical problem" rule, I think you're exaggerating the "answerable bit" here. The questions seem to be pretty specific with objective answers - I don't see why there'd be any need for discussion. And I think Jon showed that it can indeed be easily and objectively answered.

Comment: @sepp2k: Jon, as always, wrote a very nice answer. However, see his comment just above the one you wrote to me. :-)

Comment: In Wolfram Mathematica you can use a rich mathematical notation. In many languages of the Lisp family and in Forth dialects '-' is a valid character inside identifiers (and in some languages it is even allowed as a starting character).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay, so the two specific questions you've given:

1. 10<sup>2</sup> - how would you expect to type this? Programming languages tend to stick to ASCII for all but identifiers. Note that you *can* use `double x = 10e2;` in Java and C#... but the `e` form is only valid for floating point literals, not integers.

   As noted in comments, [exponentiation *is* supported in some languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation#In_programming_languages) - but I suspect it just wasn't deemed sufficiently useful to be worth the extra complexity in most.
2. An identifier with a `-` in leads to obvious ambiguity in languages with infix operators:

   ```
   int x = 10;
   int y = 4;
   int x-y = 3;
   int z = x-y;
   ```

   Is `z` equal to 3 (the value of the `x-y` variable) or is it equal to 6 (the value of subtracting `y` from `x`)? Obviously you could come up with rules about what would happen, but by removing `-` from the list of valid characters in an identifier, this ambiguity is removed. Using `_` or just casing (`nameSize`) is simpler than providing extra rules in the language. Where would you stop, anyway? What about `.` as part of an identifier, or `+`?

In general, you should be aware that languages can *easily* suffer from too many features. The C# team in particular have been quite open about how high the bar is for a new feature to make it into the language. Every new feature must be designed, specified, implemented, tested, documented, and then developers have to learn about it if they're going to understand code using it. This is not cheap, so good language designers are naturally conservative.

Comment: Note that exponentiation is supported in many languages, usually as `**`, e.g. `10**2` is 10 to the power 2 in FORTRAN *et al*.

Comment: Useful list of languages with built-in exponentiation operator here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation#In_programming_languages

Comment: To add to point 2: The reason that Lisp dialects are (pretty much?) the only languages that allow `-` (and `+` and `*` and pretty much everything else) in identifiers is that Lisp doesn't have infix operators. So there's no ambiguity there.

Comment: @sepp2k: Right. Have slightly edited to mention the importance of infix operators here :)

Comment: Jon Skeet makes points in SO as Bill Gates makes money. LoL

Answer (score 1):

[Can it be done?](https://github.com/collectiveidea/unicode_math)

> 2.⁷
>
> 1.617 * 10.ⁿ(13)

Apparently yes. You can modify languages such as ruby (define utf-8 named functions and monkey patch numeric classes) or [create User-defined literals in C++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++11#User-defined_literals) to achieve additional expressiveness.

Should it be done?

How would you type those characters?

Which unicode would you use for, say, euler's constant ? [U+2107](http://www.unicode.org/mail-arch/unicode-ml/y2010-m07/0303.html)?

I'd say we stick to code we can type and agree on.